# Search for 2 ES entries that occured with less than X minutes apart

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index with events (logs) and I want to search occurences where there is 1 event of type A followed by 1 event of type B within the next 5 mins. I'm quite new to ES so I'm sure what is the best way to achieve that, I think the aggregations might be a good way but I don't see any that fit this needs.

**Example**:
I have the following events

```
{ id: 1, timestamp: "2019-11-08 10:00", type: "A" },
{ id: 2, timestamp: "2019-11-08 10:01", type: "B" },
{ id: 3, timestamp: "2019-11-08 10:07", type: "A" },
{ id: 4, timestamp: "2019-11-08 10:10", type: "B" },
{ id: 5, timestamp: "2019-11-08 10:20", type: "B" }
```

I would like to find a way to output "correlated" events such as (the output format here is not import, I can adapt if needed, only the "correlation" information matters)

```
{ "id" : [1, 2] },
{ "id" : [3, 4] }
```

because events 1 and 2 occured within 5 mins of each other and 3 and 4 too. Event 5 is not "correlated" to any other event so it is not in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you could leverage the [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html).

First, index some documents:

```
POST test/_doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id": "1"}}
{ "id": 1, "timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:00:00", "type": "A" }
{"index":{"_id": "2"}}
{ "id": 2, "timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:01:00", "type": "B" }
{"index":{"_id": "3"}}
{ "id": 3, "timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:07:00", "type": "A" }
{"index":{"_id": "4"}}
{ "id": 4, "timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:09:00", "type": "B" }
{"index":{"_id": "5"}}
{ "id": 5, "timestamp": "2019-11-08T10:20:00", "type": "B" }
```

Then run a query that aggregates documents on 5 minutes intervals:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "history": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "5m",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll see the results you expect. In the first bucket, you'll see documents 1 and 2, in the second bucket documents 3 and 4 and document 5 in a third bucket.

Comment: Yes this seems to do exactly the job. Thanks